# What is Query Relaxation of RDF Query

Tags: sparql, rdf

I have done some reasearches on knowledge bases and I found myself in front of a new term i ve looked it up everywhere but still do not get the idea what do we mean by Query relaxation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tony Vincent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39765608/1260887) is right but I'll give an example to illustrate.

Suppose you are looking for blonde girls with dark eyes who are 170 cm tall, are PhD students working in Tokyo and whose parents are both Full Professors in the USA.

Probably, you'd get nothing.

But the system may relax the query and tell you about a few female students in Tokyo who have parents in academia.

Answer (score 2):

Query relaxation is one of the cooperative techniques that allows providing users with alternative answers instead of an empty result, 
ie.. return data satisfying query conditions with varying degrees of exactness, and also to rank the results of a query depending on how "closely" they satisfy the query conditions